# Executing cmd commands from python program

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

```
from subprocess import *

s=Popen(['C:\Python27\Scripts\pyssim',"'C:\Users\P\Desktop\1.png'",'C:\Users\P\Desktop\2.png'],stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)

out,err=s.communicate()

print out
```

The python program above executes successfully but it shows no output.
Nothing is printed on the shell.
While running command on cmd it gives output "1".

Comment: Please tell me what im doing wrong??Why don,t I get output on shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is failing because the parameters being passed to it are not what you think they are; keep in mind that backslashes are normally treated as the start of escape sequences in Python string literals.  Specifically, the `\1` and `\2` are being treated as octal character escapes, rather than digits. If you looked at the contents of `err`, you would probably find something like a file not found error.  Some possible solutions:

- Double all of the backslashes, to escape them.
- Put an 'r' in front of each string literal, to make them 'raw strings' that don't specially interpret backslashes.
- Not actually applicable in this case, but you can often just use forward slashes instead - most of Windows will happily accept them instead of backslashes, the one exception being the command line (which is what you're actually invoking here).